# Can I use Server Monitor with a non-server Mac?

Tags: networking, mac-osx, monitoring

I have a computer I use as a simple file and web server. I am simply desiring to be able to monitor load, traffic, memory usage, etc via Server Monitor. I have also downloaded an app for my iPhone which does the same thing, but it uses the same protocol that Server Monitor does.

Is it possible to get Server Monitor to recognize my non-server box as a server so I can monitor this information?

For reference, I am running 10.4.11 on this PPC box.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, Server Monitor does only hardware monitoring, not software monitoring (load, memory usage, traffice etc). Doing so requires an XServe, as this is implemented as an IMPI solution, where non-XServes are lacking the necessary hardware (management controller for LOM). This has nothing to do with the variant of MacOS (Server/non-Server) you are running.

For monitoring software parameters, you would need Server Admin, which interfaces to  the Server management service on MacOS Server, and which is not available on non-server variants of MacOS.

So, essentially, without MacOS Server on XServes, you can't use any of Apples admin tools.